# Jquery - timepicker (jonthornton) not working

Tags: jquery, timepicker

I can not get my time picker to work (i.e., nothing happens when I click on the input field). I am using this example:

https://www.jonthornton.com/jquery-timepicker/

To get:

html:

```
<!-- Time picker -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>

<!-- Time picker -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css" />

<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="startDate">Start Time:</label>
        <div class="input-group timepicker" id="timePicker1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="startTime" name="startTime" placeholder="hh:mm">
            <span class="input-group-addon" style="background-color:#ddd;">
                <i class="fa fa-clock"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#timePicker1").timepicker({'scrollDefault': 'now'});
});
```

I was looking for a Bootstrap 5 time picker; however all I could find was one I need to pay for.

Also to clock icon is not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're just targeting the wrong element, trying adding it to the input field.
Regarding the icon, you just need to load the 'Font awesome' css file.

-- Edited based on comments --

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#startTime").timepicker({
    scrollDefault: '08:00',
    timeFormat: 'H:i a',
    step: 5,
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css">

<!-- Added jQuery just so it works here on Stack Overflow too. -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Time picker -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.13.18/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>

<!-- Time picker -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.13.18/jquery.timepicker.min.css" />

<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="startTime">Start Time:</label>
    <div class="input-group timepicker" id="timePicker1">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="startTime" name="startTime" placeholder="hh:mm">
      <span class="input-group-addon" style="background-color:#ddd;">
        <i class="fa fa-clock"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
    <br><br>Sample below is just plain html.<br>
    <div class="input-group timepicker">
      <select>
        <option>Hour</option>
        <option>08</option>
        <option>09</option>
      </select>
      <select>
        <option>Minutes</option>
        <option>00</option>
        <option>05</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>15</option>
      </select>
      <select>
        <option>AM/PM</option>
        <option>AM</option>
        <option>PM</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is closer and much better. The dropdown now shows; However, it only shows half hour increments starting at 1:00 PM. I notice yours starts at 12:00 AM (which makes more sense). How do I get it to start at say 8:00 am and give 15 min increments. Better still, allow the hours and minutes to be selected individually (e.g., select the hour 1-12 then minutes 1-60 (5 min intervals would be great) then AM or PM?

Comment: @Glyn Glad it go closer. One small detail, you were calling the wrong CDN for the timepicker, so I updated that too in the answer. Regarding your additional requirements, it was possible to start at 8am and add a 5min interval. However, splitting hours/minutes/am-pm is not supported by the plugin. If you want to customize that much, you're probably better writing just plain html with `select` (Exampled added in the answer).

Comment: A very detailed and insightful reply. Thank you.